# Docker UCP Calico-node pod is unhealthy

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-swarm, docker-ucp

We are using docker-ee

```
Docker Enterprise 2.1
18.09.0-beta3
```

I installed UCP on one node and added worker nodes to it. The UCP shows node error as:
 `"Calico-node pod is unhealthy: unexpected calico-node pod condition Ready".` 
When I do the kubectl on node it shows as below

```
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces

kube-system   calico-kube-controllers-549679   1/1  Running  2  5h
kube-system   calico-node-6fk4j      1/2       CrashLoopBackOff   85         5h
kube-system   calico-node-6xldl     1/2       Running            78         5h
```

The Pod describe shows

```
kubectl describe pod calico-node-6fk4j -n kube-system:

  Warning  Unhealthy  17m (x210 over 2h)  kubelet, tclasapid004.tiffco.net  Liveness probe failed: Get http://localhost:9099/liveness: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:9099: connect: connection refused
  Warning  BackOff    7m (x410 over 2h)   kubelet, tclasapid004.tiffco.net  Back-off restarting failed container
  Warning  Unhealthy  2m (x231 over 2h)   kubelet, tclasapid004.tiffco.net  Readiness probe failed: calico/node is not ready: felix is not ready: Get http://localhost:9099/readiness: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```

We cannot run few operations with this error (Calico-node). Please help here.

Appreciate your help

Comment: It's Docker EE, contact docker enterprise support. Looks like an issue with UCP installing calico.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have multiple interfaces on that host? You need to set the auto-detect settings.

Related issue:

https://github.com/projectcalico/calico/issues/2042

> you need to set auto-detect to use another method suitable for your
>   network. E.g. adding following to calico yaml:

```
 - name: IP_AUTODETECTION_METHOD
               value: "interface=eth.*"
```

Please go throgh that issue , there are multiple reasosn with many solutions:

> I was finally able to resolve the issue. Thanks to @tmjd for the hint.
>   I had two interfaces on each of my Ubuntu VMs, enp0s3 and enp0s8. the
>   enp0s8 interface had the same IP on all the three VMs hence the calico
>   nodes on the slave were complaining about the IP conflict. To resolve
>   this problem I edited my /etc/network/interfaces file and assigned
>   static IPs to enpos8 interface. this resolved the problem.

Comment: I didn't run any kubectl apply calico files. Can you please tell me in more detail what steps I have to do to get rid off this.